# PHP form won't send information to email address "sometimes"

Tags: php, forms, sendmail

I'm a new member of this community and as you might guess, I'm having a bit of trouble! I've done a PHP form for a client in several stages... meaning it POSTs information from one level of the form to the other until the last stage actually calls a sendmail.php file which sends all gathered info to an email address.

The problem is that it doesn't ALWAYS work and it is driving crazy because I can't spot any error with the PHP... we migrated from hosting company thinking this might sorted being a problem with the PHP settings/version of the previous hosting company, but the problem persists.

Please take a look at my sendmail form:

```
<?php
$to = 'info@domain.co.uk';
$subject = 'Enquiry from domain Website';

//assigns an email address if the user leaves email field blank
if ($_POST['email'] == '') { $_POST['email'] = 'no-reply@domain.co.uk'; }

$body = '';
$body .= 'First Name: ';
$body .= $_POST['fname']. "\n". "\n";

$body .= 'Last Name: ';
$body .= $_POST['lname']. "\n". "\n";

$body .= 'Company: ';
$body .= $_POST['company']. "\n". "\n";

$body .= 'Job Role: ';
$body .= $_POST['role']. "\n". "\n";

$body .= 'Telephone: ';
$body .= $_POST['phone']. "\n". "\n";

$body .= 'Email: ';
$body .= $_POST['email']. "\n". "\n". "\n";

$body .= 'ANSWERS TO FORM QUESTIONS:'. "\n". "\n";

$body .= 'question1?: '."\n";
$body .= $_POST['question_1']. "\n". "\n";

$body .= 'question2?: '."\n";
$body .= $_POST['question_2']. "\n". "\n";

$body .= 'question3?: '."\n";
$body .= $_POST['question_3']. "\n". "\n";

$body .= 'question4?: '."\n";
$body .= $_POST['question_4']. "\n". "\n";

$body .= 'extra info?: '."\n";
$body .= $_POST['question_5']. "\n". "\n";

$message = $body;
$headers = "From: ".$_POST['email']. "\n" .
"Reply-To: ".$_POST['email']. "\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if (mail == TRUE) {

$to = $_POST['email'];
$subject = 'Thank you for using domain.co.uk';

$body2 .= "Thank you for your enquiry, it has now been sent"."\n";
$body2 .= "We will now search and find the best low cost solution providers to     assist you get your money back as quickly as possible."."\n";
$body2 .= "They will contact you (normally within 2 working hours) with a FREE risk     analysis on your requirements."."\n";
$body2 .= "Thank you for using the services of domain.co.uk";

$message = $body2;

$headers = 'From: info@domain.co.uk' . "\n" .
    'Reply-To: info@domain.co.uk' . "\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

header('Location: http://www.domain.co.uk/mobile/thankyou-mobile.php');
}
else
{
header('Location: http://www.domain.co.uk/mobile/error-mobile.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: What is this? `if (mail == TRUE)`

Comment: Also, I suggest you don't just use the `$_POST` values straight into the string. Sometimes those values are not sent or the client fools the script. That is why you should check if all the steps are set with `isset()` and if they're not empty with `empty()`. And like commented above by Pavel, what is that thing?

Comment: wouldn't it be wiser if you do if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)), instead of if (mail == true)

Comment: Hi Guys thanks for your comments so far... first of all I'm not an expert in PHP, so I used a form code from an existent website within the company (not done by me) and modified :( I asumend that the function mail returned a boolean that could be proven via TRUE or FALSE so I just left that be... but now I will check since it seems to be the problem!! thanks guys, I will update as soon as I do some tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and didn't find a reliable solution. Since then I have been using this plugin -> http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ and I haven't had a problem with it since.

Comment: Hi Severin, thank you for this, it now works perfectly using the PHP Mailer class.

Comment: Glad I could help. Mark this answer as right if it helped you :)